# Override value in application.properties

Tags: java, spring

I write desktop application which connected with `API client` and this `API` forces setting URL value

```
@Value("${ig.api.domain.URL}")
private String igApiDomainURL;
```

Setting `igApiDomainURL` showing above is in `AbstractService.class` of client api libraries so I can't change it.

I create `BeanConfiguration.java` which load `application.properties` where the `ig.api.domain.URL` was defined.

`BeanConfiguration.java` looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("application.properties")
public class BeanConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpClient httpClient() {
        return HttpClients.createDefault();
    }
}
```

... and `application.properties` contains:

```
ig.api.domain.URL=https://demo-api.ig.com/gateway/deal
```

I want change URL address defined in `application.properties` during riunning application (change the URL address depending on the type of account - DEMO/LIVE).

Any suggestions ?

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for profiles.

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: @AliDehghani nope, Spring only in Java project. My project working good (connect with api account and take data) but now the `URL` is for DEMO account and I have access to DEMO and LIVE accounts. I must find way to change this URL

Comment: @dambros Can You explain ?

Comment: @Czarq92 if I understood correctly, you want to load different values for that property according to different envs. If you use Spring profiles, you can easily achieve this with some annotations representing the profiles and passing the profile as an argument to the JVM.

Comment: @dambros Yes, You understood well :) Hmm can You write basic example (it helps me to understand) ? Ex. I run app window and choose from list DEMO or LIVE and when I choose first of them it should load appropriate link.

Comment: @Czarq92 check the given answer and let me know if you couldn't understand something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long discussion, what finally worked for this **very specific** scenario was doing something like this:

Create a property file for each possible profile you want, like:

```
application-dev.properties
application-prod.properties
```

Properties content example:

```
property.i.want=abcd
```

Set the env before creating the ApplicationContext:

```
System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "dev");
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext  context =
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"spring.xml"});
```

Then set the property source manually, i.e.:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer() throws IOException {
    String profile = System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active");
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pspc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(String.format("application-%s.properties", profile));
    Properties props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
    pspc.setProperties(props);
    pspc.setPropertySources();
    return pspc;
}
```

Definitly not the prettiest solution though.

Comment: It looks nice but I have no idea where I should put this `-Dspring.profiles.active=prod`. I must set before it load `ApplicationContext` but loading `ApplicationContext` is in basic java class NOT Spring class. Ex I have `String accountType` and HOW put it in ?

Comment: You set it as a VM option... how do you start your application? Just pass it to the JVM when you start it.

Comment: I run basic main class, create object and run method `initializeContext` which load `ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/public-api-client-spring-context.xml");`, next `applicationContext.getBean("igservice");`, bean look like `<bean name="igservice" class="com.goodsoft.stockbox.ig.business.service.IgServiceImpl"/>` and the `IgServiceImpl` is annotated with `@Component`, `@Autowired` beans and contain methods like `connect`, `openPositions` etc

Comment: The main method you run receives an array of arguments, so just pass that value to the main method. What are you using to run the main method? IDE or cmd/bash?

Comment: Example:  I have `String choosenAccoutType = DEMO` before run `initializeContext()` and How can I choose profile which should be loaded ? In pseudocode `switch(choosenAccoutType): case DEMO: ??? case LIVE: ???` (What write in ???). Because I have no idea how set this `${spring.profiles.active}` in your example `@PropertySource("classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties")`

Comment: You shouldn't have this value in the class, like I said it has to go as a param to the VIRTUAL MACHINE. See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html).

Comment: I understand but I want get this value from GUI app, not from running up with arguments. Example: my app is running and I have window with `dropList`, I choose from `dropList` type `DEMO` and when I click button `Connect`, next should load my configurations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108505/discussion-between-dambros-and-czarq92).